# Audio Selection Activity started using getActivity().startActivityForResult() not getting closed on low memory

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, back-stack, onactivityresult

I have an activity that uses fragments. From one of the fragments I am calling a song selection intent using:

```
Intent pickAudioIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
           android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
mActivity.startActivityForResult(pickAudioIntent, 1);
```

and without selecting any song I minimizes the application by pressing HOME key.
After minimizing, play with other applications to consume system memory.

When there is no more memory left for new processes, the Android OS destroyed our application's Activity but the Audio Selection Activity still remains on the top and not destroyed. When I go back with the result data, the calling fragment's activity recreates itself (as it was on the backstack) and the result was discarded.

Can anyone suggest, how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Um, what exactly is the issue? There is no requirement that Android terminate somebody else's process before yours, and termination of processes does not directly remove things from tasks/back stacks. So, in general, this sounds like the appropriate system behavior.

Comment: My activity doesn't get removed from the back stack but it gets recreated and the onActivityResult of the calling fragment is not called.
However, it is called in normal scenario

Comment: I have heard about problems with `startActivityForResult()` on a fragment. You might wish to call `startActivityForResult()` on an activity and have `onActivityResult()` on that activity, which can then route the results back to the fragment by some other means.